# Using BeautifulSoup to extract span text

Tags: python, macos, selenium, beautifulsoup, terminal

I have this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
text_intro = soup.find( 'div', { 'id' : 'gerais' } )
usernam = soup.select('#main > aside > div > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3) ')

print( '', 'Result_text_intro -> ', texto_intro )
print( '', 'Result_usernam -> ', usernam )
```

It prints this:

```
Result_usernam ->  [<span style="color:#F5B518;font-weight:bold"> (TestUser)</span>]
```

How can i get only the "(TestUser)" from the span?

Comment: first you should read all documentation for `BeautifulSoup` - and you would know that there is `.get_text()` or `.string`. But you have to also see that you have `[ ... ]` so you have list and you will have to use `for`-loop or `usernam[0]` to get first element from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `[ ]` so you have list and you have to use `for`-loop to work with every element separatelly or `[0]` to get only first element.

And then you can use `.get_text()` or `.string`
(in some tutorials you can see `.text` but `.string` is preferred in newer versions)

```
print('Result_usernam -> ', usernam[0].get_text(strip=True) )

print('Result_usernam -> ', usernam[0].string.strip() )
```

If you get more elements

```
for item in usernam:
    print('Result_usernam -> ', item.get_text(strip=True) )

for item in usernam:
    print('Result_usernam -> ', item.string.strip() )
```

---

Doc: [.get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) and [.string](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string)

---

`select()` always gives list (even if there is no results or only one result) but there is also `select_one()` to get only first result and then you don't need `[0]` or `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "text" ?

```py
print( '', 'Result_usernam -> ', usernam.text)
```

Comment: see `[..]` in output - it is list so you need `usernam[0].text`